# NSDateFormatter swapping between Style and Format

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsdateformatter

Is it safe to use the same `NSDateFormatter` and swap between Style and Format definitions? For example:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter new];
df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
df.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
NSLog(@"Medium Style / Medium Time: %@", [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
df.dateFormat = @"MMM/d/yy hh:mm:ss";
NSLog(@"Custom Format: %@", [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterFullStyle;
df.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
NSLog(@"Full Style/ No Time: %@", [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]); 
// ^-- how does it know to stop using the format I set before?
```

In the very last line, how does the `NSDateFormatter` know to stop using the date format I specified before? Is this safe to do reliably?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date formatter uses the `style` if `format` is `nil`. So add the following line:

```
df.dateFormat = nil;
```

when you want to go back to use the `style`.